How do I vectorize this expression with Numpy?
I am trying to compute the array "matrix" below. How can I do this using vectorized functions of NumPy?
x = np.array([
    [2, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [3, 2, 1],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [2, 3, 0]
])

y = np.array([
    [405, 200, 150],
    [200, 300, 150],
    [150, 100, 105],
    [425, 200, 250],
    [500, 620, 300]
])

matrix = np.zeros((5,3,4))  
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(3):
       matrix[i,j,x[i,j]] = y[i,j]

I tried this:
vmatrix = np.zeros((5,3,4))

vmatrix[:,:,x] = y

But it does not work...

You can do this in one line by turning x into one-hot vectors (using methods inspired by this answer) and reshaping y to make the dimensions ready for broadcasting:
matrix2 = np.eye(4)[x] * np.expand_dims(y, axis=-1)

print(np.equal(matrix, matrix2).all()) # True


y[..., None] is even more succinct and saves needing to retype the shape.

@nneonneo Thanks for pointing that out! I realized that one can also use expand_dims to avoid having to know the dimensions of y, and the method itself helps clarify what's being done.

Thank you @AlexDuchnowski! May I ask you why axis = -1 in expand_dims?

@MBlrd No problem! Here, axis=-1 indicates that the shape of y should be changed from  (5,3) to (5,3,1). Specifically, it's saying that the 1 being inserted into the dimensions should be at the end (just how l[-1] gets the last element of a python list l). You can get a sense for how this works by printing the shape of the output of expand_dims and using different values for axis (you could try out 0, 1, 2, and -1). This will give you shapes like (1,5,3) and (5,1,3) depending on the selected axis.

@AlexDuchnowski y[..., np.newaxis] then (np.newaxis is an alias for None; it serves to self-document the expansion syntax here).

FWIW: I benchmarked the two solutions. The np.eye solution is generally a bit slower (~3x for final dimension k=4 as in the question for a 100x100 array) and scales worse than the meshgrid-indexing solution for larger k, probably because of the need to do a full multiplication over all the elements. On the other hand, it is extremely elegant and will be a huge improvement over a for loop in any case.

Benchmark results here: https://pastebin.com/LPw9Mzhd

Use fancy indexing with a meshgrid:
ix, iy = np.ogrid[:5, :3]
matrix = np.zeros((5, 3, 4))
matrix[ix, iy, x] = y

